# Eliminar sub item dentro de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy tratando de eliminar un sub item dentro de un arreglo de objetos, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
especialidad: [{
                    id: 1,
                    nombre: "Informatica",
                    cantidad_horas: 200,
                    usuarios: {
                        usuario1: {
                            id: 2,
                            nombre: "Pepipo"
                        },
                        usuario2: {
                            id: 3,
                            nombre: "Juan"
                        }
                    }
                }],
```

quiero eliminar un usuario dentro de ese arreglo, lo que llevo mientras es esto en el metodo,

```
this.esp.map(function (especialidad) {
                    if (especialidad.id === id) {
                        especialidad.forEach(function (currentValue, index, arr) {
                            if (especialidad.user[index] === es) {
                                especialidad.user.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
```

el resultado deberia quedar así,

```
especialidad: [{
                    id: 1,
                    nombre: "Informatica",
                    cantidad_horas: 200,
                    usuarios: {
                        usuario1: {
                            id: 2,
                            nombre: "Pepipo"
                        }
                    }
                }],
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
let json = {especialidad:[{
                    id: 1,
                    nombre: "Informatica",
                    cantidad_horas: 200,
                    usuarios:{

                        usuario1: {
                            id: 2,
                            nombre: "Pepipo"
                        },

                        usuario2: {
                            id: 3,
                            nombre: "Juan"
                        },
                        usuario3: {
                            id: 4,
                            nombre: "Marta"
                        },
                         usuario4: {
                            id: 5,
                            nombre: "Maria"
                        }
                    }
                }]
                };
//nombre del usuario a remover 
let remover_usuario = "juan";
// hacemos un bucle tipo obj con for in de json["especialidad"][0]["usuarios"]
for(let i in json["especialidad"][0]["usuarios"]){
 // validamos que el nombre cambiado a minuscula sea igual al que buscamos
  if(json.especialidad[0].usuarios[i].nombre.toLowerCase() == remover_usuario.toLowerCase()){
  // si el nombre es igual eliminamos esa entrada
   delete json.especialidad[0].usuarios[i];
   // y cancelamos el bucle
   break;
 }
}

//usuarios restantes
console.log(json["especialidad"][0]["usuarios"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const especialidades = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Informatica",
    cantidad_horas: 200,
    usuarios: {
      usuario1: {
        id: 2,
        nombre: "Pepipo"
      },
      usuario2: {
        id: 3,
        nombre: "Juan"
      }
    }
  }
];

const mapped = especialidades.map(item => {
  for (let key in item.usuarios) {
    if (item.usuarios[key].id == 3) {
      const {[key]: omitir, ...notuser} = item.usuarios
      item.usuarios = notuser
    }
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped, null, 2))
```

Lo que hice fue iterar primero, iterar las especialidades, después iterar los usuarios de esa especialidad, dentro validar si el *id* de usuario es igual al que estás buscando si es igual con ayuda del destructuring de es6, omito el usuario y lo asigno a la propiedad `usuarios` dentro de la especialidad. Si copias y pegas el código podrás ver el resultado.
Solo validé el id del usuario, igual podrías agregar una validación antes para validar el id de la especialidad u otras cosas que necesites.